# network UNCLAIMED Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, network-interface

I was facing some issues with wifi disconnection. So I followed some askubuntu forum answers and solved the problem by manually installing the wifi device. But still I had to follow the first answer of [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760838/how-do-i-get-an-rt3290-wireless-card-to-work) question to make it work on every start up. I had to run these two command on every start up to make make wifi network work.

```
sudo ifconfig eno1 up
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Then suddenly it stopped working now. Now when I ran `sudo lshw -C network` and it gives me this.

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Network controller
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b5510000-b551ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 08
       serial: a0:1d:48:d1:23:d9
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 ip=192.168.1.3 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:42 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b5404000-b5404fff memory:b5400000-b5403fff
```

it says network UNCLAIMED. Why is that ? How can I solve that issue ?

When I run `lspci` it shows me my wifi adapter model as

```
08:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
```

I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760838/how-do-i-get-an-rt3290-wireless-card-to-work). But it says that it will work when secure boot is disabled. But the thing is I've already disabled secure boot and I was working fine about two hours ago.

How can I solve this? Any help would be much appreciated.